# print a cell array as .txt in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text-files, printf

I have a cell array that needs to be printed in a .txt file according to a specific format.  I have tried some of the online help (including matlab central `dlmcell` but even that is not giving me the desired answer.  Delimiter is \t.

```
cellarray = { ...
        'AAPL' '2/20/2011' 100.5 
        'MSFT' '2/15/2011' 43.4551
            } ;
```

The output should be in a .txt file with the following format: (using tab delimiter)

```
"AAPL"    "2/20/2011"    100.5
"MSFT"    "2/15/2011"    43.4551
```

The cell will have minimum of 8000 rows and a maximum of 15000.  No rows would have empty columns.  Is a vectorized solution possible?  Shall appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will work for your example:

```
C = cellarray.';
fid = fopen('file.dlm', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '"%s"\t"%s"\t%g\n', C{:});
fclose(fid);
```

MATLAB reuses the formatting string until it runs out of inputs. In principle, you could construct the formatting string first:

```
fstr = '';
for ic = 1:size(cellarray,2)
   switch class(cellarray{1,ic})
       case 'char'
           fstr = [fstr '"%s"'];
       otherwise
           % Assume numeric
           fstr = [fstr '%g'];
   end
   if ic < size(cellarray,2), fstr = [fstr '\t']; else fstr = [fstr '\n']; end
end
```

Then

```
C = cellarray.';
fid = fopen('file.dlm', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, fstr, C{:});
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: thanks.  But both the solutions give the same errror ->
Error 1

??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.
Error in ==> 
fprintf( fid, '"%s"\t"%s"\t%g\n', C{:} );

Error 2

Comment: switch class(cellarray{1,ic})

Comment: That means that `cellarray` isn't a cell array.

Comment: u r right Nzbuu...there was a small bug in my actual code.. my bad! sorry.  thanks..it works great.

Answer (score 3):

I often use combination of DLMWRITE and XLSWRITE. DLMWRITE is used to make a text file, so XLSWRITE will not generate the file in Excel format, but will leave it as a text.

```
filename = 'file.txt';
dlmwrite(filename, 1)
xlswrite(filename, cellarray)
```

Note that on OS where COM is not available (like Linux) XLSWRITE write to text, so you don't need the call to DLMWRITE.

---

**UPDATE**

This method does not work anymore with the latest versions of MATLAB (since probably R2012b). `xlswrite` always writes to Excel-formatted file.

However, since R2013b MATLAB introduced [TABLES](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html), and [WRITETABLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) function works great if cell array can be converted to a table (check [CELL2TABLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2table.html) function).

Comment: thanks Yuk. It works fine but it takes 18 seconds for printing out 3 cols for 15k rows.  I am hoping for a faster alternative.  I'm not even sure if it is possible now..

Comment: `xlswrite` is pretty slow because it needs to launch and connect to Excel first. But that's probably more than a couple of seconds.

Comment: This is a great way to write the output without going through the messy for loosps...thanks