# Write cell into a text file

Tags: matlab, text, cell

I have a 39x4 cell:

```
'ID'    'x' 'y' 'z'
459     34  -49 -20
464     36  -38 -22
639     40  -47 -27
719     35  -52 -20
725     42  -45 -18
727     46  -47 -26
...
```

I would like to write all this to a text file. I've tried the following:

```
fileID = fopen('test2.txt','w');
formatSpec='%s %d %d %d';
fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,P{:});
fclose(fileID);
```

However, if I do this, I get the error that fprintf is not defined for 'cell' input. I've seen a couple of examples like this one about how to [print a cell array as .txt in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565617/print-a-cell-array-as-txt-in-matlab) this one about how to [write cell array of combined string and numerical input into text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214154/write-cell-array-of-combined-string-and-numerical-input-into-text-file) but they don't seem to fit very well without some clunky modifications.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is due to the fact that the first row of your cell array contains only strings while the other rows contain only numbers.  Your format specifier currently assumes the first element to write per row is a string while the others are integers. You'll have to accommodate for a special case where writing to the first line consists of just strings.

Something like this should work:

```
%// Open the file for writing
fileID = fopen('test2.txt','w');

%// First write the headers to file
fprintf(fileID, '%s %s %s %s\n', P{1,:});

%// Transpose because writing is done in column-major order
Pt = P.'; %'

%// Now write each row to file
fprintf(fileID, '%d %d %d %d\n', Pt{:,2:end});

%// Close the file
fclose(fileID);
```

Take note at the format specifier for the first row consists of entirely strings, then the format specifier for the rows after consists only of integers.  Also take note that I needed to **transpose** the cell array because using `fprintf` naturally writes matrices in column-major order so in order to write your matrices in a row-major fashion, the transposition is required before printing and we'll also need to access the columns of your data instead of the rows to accommodate.

Comment: Thank you, rayryeng. The line taking care of the header doesn't work. When I run `fprintf(fileID, '%s %s %s %s\n', P{1,:});` I still get the error that fprintf is not defined for cell input. Am I missing something?

Comment: @A.Rainer The code works for me.... I declared `P` to be a cell array like you have in your code.  I'm confused as to why you're getting that error.

Comment: This also may be related to the MATLAB version you are using.  What MATLAB version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2014a. If I do `whos P`, I get `Name       Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes:  P         40x4             19200  cell `. If I don't include the header in P and skip the header line, everything else works.

Comment: That's weird.  I basically took the above text and placed them as individual elements in a cell array, then used the above code to write to file.  Can you edit your post and show us what a few rows of the cell array `P` look like?

Comment: @A.Rainer I can't reproduce your error. I constructed the cell array myself then used the above code to write things to file.  Here's a copy of my command prompt in MATLAB to show you what I did: https://codeshare.io/HC1G5

Comment: Thank you, rayreng. I'll look at it a bit more. If nothing else, I can skip the header. it's not a big deal. I do appreciate your help!

Comment: There was indeed an error in my code. Your code is correct.

Comment: @A.Rainer ah I see. no problem at all! What was the error if I may ask?

Comment: When creating the header in P, instead of `P{1,1}='ID'` I had `P{1,1}=cellstr('ID');` so that was a cell within a cell. Silly error as I copied this line of code from something else I had created previously.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is most probably being caused due to the following line in your code:

```
fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,P{:}); % P{:} returns all the cells in P matrix
```

Also the `formatSpec` you have specified will not work for all your rows since the first row is in a different format. You will need two calls to fprintf as:

```
fprintf(fileID,'%s %s %s %s\n',P{1,:});
fprintf(fileID,'%d %d %d %d\n',P{2:end,:});
```

Comment: Be mindful that `fprintf` using matrices accesses elements in column-major order.  You'll need to transpose `P` then access the second column to the last column in order to write this correctly to file.